# How to convert video from URI to byte[]

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have captured video and I get a URI of that video.

How to load the content pointed to by that URI into `byte[]` structure?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

- [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html),
- [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), and
- [`File(URI uri)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29).

Code example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(yourUri));

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n;
while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
    baos.write(buf, 0, n);

byte[] videoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is very old, however, I was searching for an answer to a similiar question and I found a very simple way to do this. Bear in mind I did this in Kotlin but the syntax should be very similiar.

```
val videoBytes = FileInputStream(File(videoPath)).use { input -> input.readBytes() }
```

`File()` takes a `URI` or `String`. In my case I converted the `Uri` to `String`.

Using `FileInputStream().use {}` will also close the input stream.

The code below is the method I used to convert the `Uri` into a `String`:

```
    private fun getVideoPathFromURI(uri: Uri): String
{
    var path: String = uri.path // uri = any content Uri

    val databaseUri: Uri
    val selection: String?
    val selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    if (path.contains("/document/video:"))
    { // files selected from "Documents"
        databaseUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        selection = "_id=?"
        selectionArgs = arrayOf(DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri).split(":")[1])
    }
    else
    { // files selected from all other sources, especially on Samsung devices
        databaseUri = uri
        selection = null
        selectionArgs = null
    }
    try
    {
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.LATITUDE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.LONGITUDE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN)

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(databaseUri,
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0])
            videoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    catch (e: Exception)
    {
        Log.e("TAG", e.message, e)
    }
    return videoPath
}
```