# Load video in an Activity and display it in another one

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

Here is the code I use to load my video:

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video);

videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));

videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                videoView.start();
                loader.loaded.set(true);
            }
        });
```

My application contains a "Loading Activity" and I would like to use it to load my video before going to the next Activity.

Is it possible to load a video in an Activity, but to display it in another one?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

PS:

Just in case someone asks, the following line enables me to hide the videoView before it is completely loaded (because a big black square is displayed before the video is fully loaded):

```
loader.loaded.set(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move `views` between activities. You should instead use `Fragments`. Load the video in one fragment and pass it to the other

Answer (score 1):

You can load the video in the loading activity and store it in a custom class that implements Serializable. Then, you pass the video data with an Intent object while going to the next activity.

Comment: You can't Serializable a view

Comment: You don't need to move the whole view to the other activity, you only need to move the video (in a byte array or something) and have the view in the new activity.

Comment: So, I can store my video after it is loaded? But how exactly? @DGounaris

Comment: Once you are in onPrepared, you can use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913465/1988355) to store the loaded video in a byte[], since you know the URI. Then you can switch to the other activity with an intent containing that byte[]. However, now that I think of it, it may be double the work for no real reason. Consider using fragments as the other comment suggests instead.